# How do you add formatted number column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

A column that displays the last four digits of the card_number column in this format:
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1234. In other words, use Xs for the first 12 digits of the card
number and actual numbers for the last four digits of the number.

```
SELECT Card_number, length(card_number) as cardLength, 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-'
+ right(card_number,4) as lastfourdigits

FROM orders;
```

Comment: What you really want is data masking. While you can roll your own functionality, there exist ready-made solutions. MySQL Enterprise edition provide a [plugin](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/masking.html), and it looks like [someone was kind enough to mirror that for MySQL Community edition](https://github.com/gdsotirov/mysql-play/tree/master/DataMask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL strings can be concatenated with the `concat()` function, not with the `+` operator.

```
SELECT card_number,
       length(card_number) as cardlength,
       concat('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-', right(card_number, 4)) as lastfourdigits
       FROM orders;
```

Comment: than you very much